# Does it make sense to install mysql separately after installing wamp server

Tags: database, web-applications, wamp

To start with i am a novice but have immense faith in technology.Q- I have installed
wamp package and mysql server as well. it it necessary to do so? also , i was willing to connect my web applications in netbeans to database.now do i need to connect it separately and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

WAMP comes with MySQL and phpmyadmin as a database manager, so you should be set! Just go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin